# webcache behave differently then site

Tags: caching, googlebot

`http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.domain.com` - when I navigate by this URL , it render me 404 page on my site , but when I go directly on my site , it works properly and there isn't 404 page , all work fine , is webpache parse it differently , or what can be the problem , how can I find out the issue ?

I have found this issue https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5801, but don't see any solution on this topic , I use `readt-router`

Answer (score 1):

https://medium.com/@georgejustin22/why-google-web-cache-is-not-as-important-for-seo-as-you-think-ce4026c1eb6d found this article and understood that this isn't much important to see there data, it shows `404` because your site executed on another domain and it `react-router` doesn't work properly, it doesn't match your route and render last page on your routing , in my case for sure it was `404` page